# Exact String Alignment Retrieval in EMAIL Content

Tags: java, email, mime-types

```
StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(sw);

String rowFormat = "%8s %8s %8s %8s%n";
pw.printf(rowFormat, "Col A", "Col B", "Col C", "Col XY");
pw.printf(rowFormat, "A", "19", "Car", "55");
pw.printf(rowFormat, "X", "21", "Train C", "-4");
pw.printf(rowFormat, "B", "-9", "Bike", "0");
String message = sw.toString();
System.out.println(message);
```

The above program prints the following table and the alignment is perfect.

```
Col A    Col B    Col C   Col XY   
    A       19      Car       55   
    X       21  Train C       -4   
    B       -9     Bike        0
```

Instead of printing the `string message`, I am passing the string to another function which sends email with the content of the mail as the `string message`.

```
mail.setContent(message.toString(),"text/plain");
```

This is how I am setting the content as message in my mail.

But the alignment of the table is not appropriate as I do receive while printing the string. What must be done such that I receive the content of my mail as similar as the printing format of the string. Please advise on this regard.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its good to build a `HTML` markup for this, i.e. `<table>`, and set that in your `mail` like this,

```
mail.setContent(message.toString(),"text/html);
```

Comment: Am handling all the content of the mail in a single String and passing that to the email function. Hence am asking for the possibilities of modifying the current program.

Comment: @LGAP: Of course, modify your program to use HTML mark-up to format. Otherwise, you can always have formatting issue, with different font faces and font sizes.

Comment: Okay.. i will try the same and let you know of my updates. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The email looks fine to me (on Outlook). What email client are you using? Maybe it is applying formatting to the message, even though it is Plain Text.

Comment: I am not using any email client like Outlook.

Comment: Then how are you viewing the email?